# Why can't I use the LLDB to print out a string literal with a ¢ character?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, runtime-error, lldb, parsing-error

While in a breakpoint during a XCTest (and later during a normal run), I encountered something... odd. I think the screenshot below explains my problem:

[image: Two calls of the LLDB, one reading <code>po @"12"</code>, with the successful print below reading <code>12</code>. The next is <code>po @"\u0031\u0032"</code> and also prints <code>12</code>. The next reads <code>po @"12¢"</code>, with an error below saying "An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array". The third reads <code>po @"\u0031\u0032\u00A2"</code>, the fourth reads <code>po @"¢"</code>, and the fifth <code>po @"\u00A2"</code> and all have the same issue.]

**Why does it claim `An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array`?** It appears as if its attempt to translate my `@""` `NSString` literal sugar into an `NSString` initializer-with-C-string was unsuccessful, but why?

Also, I've tested many other strings with the `¢` character or its Unicode escape sequence, and they all have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug.  Please file it with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Static string construction involves some compiler magic, and apparently lldb isn't getting that right when the string contains high-bit characters.  You can achieve the same effect in the expression parser by using one of the NSString constructors:

```
(lldb) expr NSString *$newstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "Something¢"]
(lldb) expr $newstr
(__NSCFString *) $newstr = 0x00000001007000a0 @"Something¢"
```

Then you can use $newstr in future expressions.

Comment: One caution here is that the NSString constructors return auto-released objects, so if you wanted to assign this string to some pointer in your program, you need to retain it before pass it back to the ARC world or it will get released and go bad.  If you are just using it in expressions in lldb, that is not necessary, however.

Answer (score 1):

Must be a bug with LLDB expression parser. Even debuggers have bugs..

You can look for the error in [IRForTarget](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-112/source/Expression/IRForTarget.cpp) which is used by llvm [ClangExpressionParser](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-112/source/Expression/ClangExpressionParser.cpp).